# Create a Custom Field Type

Tags: custom-list, custom-field-types

I would like to create a Custom Field Type by following the link [enter link description here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhijmk/how-to-create-custom-multicolumn-field-types-in-sharepoint-2/) . Everything looks good. I can deploy the project successfully. However, when I create a new column, the custom field type is not displayed. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have copied fldtypes_FieldTypeName.xml file to SPHive\TEMPLATE\XML folder.